# Extensions of p-adic number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, fields, class-field-theory, local-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p-$adic rational field. Let $E/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a fixed finite extension. On this site, I define a finite extension $F/E$ to be "good" if there exists an intermediate extension $K/E$ of $F/E$ such that
$K/E$ is totally ramified and $F/K$ is unramified.

My question is, for any finite extension $L/E$, does there exist a "good" extension $F/E$, such that $L$ is contained in $F$? Since we only care about the inclusion $L\subset F$, we can enlarge $L$, such that $L/E$ is a Galois extension.

If $L/E$ is an abelian extension, the answer to my question is yes. From class field theory, we can construct the Lubin–Tate extension $E_\pi/E$, which is totally ramified. The maximal abelian extension of $E$ is
obtained by the composite of $E_\pi$ and the maximal unramified extension of $E$. Hence we can find a "good" extension $F/E$ such that $F\supset L$.

Since this question looks rather fundamental, I wonder if this question was considered and solved by anyone else before. Any help will be appreciated.

As [commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458265/extensions-of-of-p-adic-number-field#comment1187154_458265) by @re'em waxman, I'd like to make it more precise.
Let $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{al}}$ denote the algebraic closure. The comment by @re'em waxman suggested me to  find an algebraic extension $K/E$, such that $K\cap E^{\mathrm{ur}}=E$ (it is the same as $K/E$ being totally ramified) and $KE^{\mathrm{ur}}=\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{al}}$. From infinite Galois theory, it is equivalent to finding a closed subgroup $H$of the absolute Galois group $G_E$, such that $I_E\cap H=\{1\} $ and $I_E H=G_E$, where $I_E$ denotes the inertia group of $E$. In other words, it is equivalent to finding a subgroup $H$, such that the composite of natural maps $H\hookrightarrow G_E\twoheadrightarrow G_{E}/I_E$ is an isomorphism of profinite groups. Finally, it is equivalent to the following short exact sequence of profinite groups splitting:
$$0\longrightarrow I_E\longrightarrow G_E\longrightarrow G_E/I_E\cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}\longrightarrow 0.$$
One suggested $H$ is taken to be the closure of the subgroup generated by any chosen lifted Frobenius $\tilde{\varphi}$. But I don't know if this is a correct $H$. In other words, does the group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G_E$ by  $1\mapsto \tilde{\varphi}$ extend to a continuous group homomorphism $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\to G_E$?

Since $G_E$ is profinite,
$$ \operatorname{Hom}(\hat{\mathbb{Z}},G_E)=
\varprojlim\operatorname{Hom}(\hat{\mathbb{Z}},G_E/U)\cong \varprojlim G_E/U=G_E,$$
where the inverse limit runs through open normal subgroups $U$ of $G_E$. We see any homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G_E$ extends continuously to  $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, as [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458265/extensions-of-of-p-adic-number-field#comment1187238_458265) by @David Loeffler. So my problem is solved.

Comment: Can't we use the same argument? lift the Frobenius element and take the fixed by this lift. This field $K$ will be totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and I think we have $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}=K\mathbb{Q}_p^{un}$ and we can use the same argument. I might be horribly wrong here.

Comment: @re'em waxman Thank you for your kind advice. I have edited the problem to include your consideration.

Comment: If $G$ is a profinite group then doesn't any homomorphism $\mathbf{Z} \to G$ extend to $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$?

Comment: @David Loeffler Yes, you are right.  So the problem is solved. I was confused before. Thank you!

Comment: See also section 3 of this article, which doesn't use infinite Galois theory: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2015-143-12/S0002-9939-2015-12634-2/

Comment: See also this MathOverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262167/totally-ramified-subextension-in-a-finite-extension-of-mathbfq-p

Comment: TeX note: `\lim` already exists, and behaves more as expected than `\mathrm{lim}`, so there's no need for constructs like $\mathrm{lim}_\leftarrow$ `\mathrm{lim}_\leftarrow`.  Already $\displaystyle\lim_\leftarrow$ `\displaystyle\lim_\leftarrow` behaves better, but there's even an existing construct, $\varprojlim$ `\varprojlim`, that does that.  I edited accordingly.  (In general, `\operatorname` is what you want for, well, operator names.)